# Sql Server Management Studio 2012 tries to convert nvarchar to datetime during import

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am publishing an ASP.NET MVC 5 solution from my development box to my hosting provider. I have been using entity framework with localdb v11.0 on my dev box. My hosting provider provides a SQL Server 10.0 database.

I am attempting to move my entire localdb to a SQL Server 10.0 db at my hosting provider including creating and populating destination tables from scratch using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio Import wizard.

I noticed that the wizard's default column mapping for the destination tables was trying to create what should be nvarchar columns as date columns at the destination in every table. So I manually changed all the incorrect mappings. However when I executed the actual import, the tables created at the destination had columns which should have been defined as nvarchar as date instead, so the import process ignored my corrected mappings and failed as soon as data was uploaded.

I would like to know if this is a known bug in SQL Server Management Studio, and if so, is there an easy workaround. If not I will have to do this a different way which will take a lot longer, which isn't the end of the world, but would be an annoying waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Used the "Edit SQL" button within column mapping to check that the column mapping had been changed. I noticed that it had for nearly all columns, but not all, so manually changed it for the others for which datatype had erroneously remained as Date.